Using compileSdk 35 requires Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.1.0 or higher
After upgrade Flutter we facing issue
┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Using compileSdk 35 requires Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.1.0 or higher.                    │
│  Please upgrade to a newer AGP version. The version of AGP that your project uses is likely      │
│  defined in:                                                                                     │
│ G:\Flutter\Testing Project\test\android\settings.gradle,                                │
│ in the 'plugins' closure (by the number following "com.android.application").                    │
│  Alternatively, if your project was created with an older version of the templates, it is likely │
│ in the buildscript.dependencies closure of the top-level build.gradle:                           │
│ G:\Flutter\Testing Project\test\android\build.gradle,                                   │
│ as the number following "com.android.tools.build:gradle:".                                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│  Finally, if you have a strong reason to avoid upgrading AGP, you can temporarily lower the      │
│  compileSdk version in the following file:                                                       │
│ G:\Flutter\Testing Project\test\android\app\build.gradle                                │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

I tried change version 8.1 to 8.4 : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
but not solved issue

Create new flutter app and observe new versions and structure of AGP and gradle from files
gradle-wrapper.properties
settings.gradle
build.gradle
app/build.gradle
More over, we don't know how old your project, take a look at AndroidManifest file

In addition to what you did, you may try also this
Modify android>settings.gradle file with this

id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false


finally i got the solution's form Flutter GitHub issue part: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156304

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
